# Training ResNet50 with Tensorflow 1.5.0 on RTX 3070 problems

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I trying to run on a docker created as follows:

```
docker run --gpus=all -it -p "8888:8888" -v "/home/miguel/ml-resnet-50/:/notebooks/" --name ml-resnet-50 tensorflow/tensorflow:1.5.0-gpu-py3 jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root
```

On a Linux PC Ubuntu 20.04 with RTX 3070 Nvidia Card the follow code:

```
model.fit(
    x=imgs_train,
    y=clss_train,
    batch_size=16,
    epochs=2,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(imgs_val, clss_val)
    )
```

And getting following error:

> InternalError: Blas SGEMM launch failed : m=48400, n=64, k=64
> [[Node: res2a_branch2a/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC",
> dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
> use_cudnn_on_gpu=true,
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](max_pooling2d/MaxPool,
> res2a_branch2a/kernel/read)]]      [[Node: loss/mul/_2859 =
> _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
> send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
> send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_15435_loss/mul",
> tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>
> Caused by op 'res2a_branch2a/Conv2D', defined at:   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
> "**main**", mod_spec)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line
> 16, in 
> app.launch_new_instance()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
> line 658, in launch_instance
> app.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line
> 478, in start
> self.io_loop.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line
> 177, in start
> super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888,
> in start
> handler_func(fd_obj, events)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
> line 277, in null_wrapper
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
> line 440, in _handle_events
> self._handle_recv()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
> line 472, in _handle_recv
> self._run_callback(callback, msg)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
> line 414, in _run_callback
> callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
> line 277, in null_wrapper
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
> 283, in dispatcher
> return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
> 233, in dispatch_shell
> handler(stream, idents, msg)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
> 399, in execute_request
> user_expressions, allow_stdin)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line
> 208, in do_execute
> res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line
> 537, in run_cell
> return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 2728, in run_cell
> interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 2850, in run_ast_nodes
> if self.run_code(code, result):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
> line 2910, in run_code
> exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 2, in 
> model = get_model()   File "", line 4, in get_model
> model = ResNet50(include_top=False,input_shape=(pipeline['img_height'],
> pipeline['img_width'], 3))   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/applications/resnet50.py",
> line 235, in ResNet50
> x = conv_block(x, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='a', strides=(1, 1))   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/applications/resnet50.py",
> line 122, in conv_block
> name=conv_name_base + '2a')(input_tensor)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py",
> line 258, in **call**
> output = super(Layer, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py",
> line 652, in **call**
> outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/convolutional.py",
> line 167, in call
> outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py",
> line 838, in **call**
> return self.conv_op(inp, filter)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py",
> line 502, in **call**
> return self.call(inp, filter)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py",
> line 190, in **call**
> name=self.name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py",
> line 639, in conv2d
> data_format=data_format, dilations=dilations, name=name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
> line 787, in _apply_op_helper
> op_def=op_def)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 3160, in create_op
> op_def=op_def)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 1625, in **init**
> self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas SGEMM launch failed :
> m=48400, n=64, k=64    [[Node: res2a_branch2a/Conv2D =
> Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1],
> padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true,
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](max_pooling2d/MaxPool,
> res2a_branch2a/kernel/read)]]      [[Node: loss/mul/_2859 =
> _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
> send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
> send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_15435_loss/mul",
> tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Any idea why it happeds?

Comment: Looks like a gpu-related error. Tensorflow 1.5.0 was compiled against a fairly old version of CUDA (9.0 iirc) make sure you have CUDA 9.0 and cudnn 7.X.X on that docker image.

Comment: As per the Tensorflow doc Tf-GPU 1.5.0 requires CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7. Make sure you installed Nvidia-docker before Installing Tensorflow docker. Take a look at [Tensorflow build doc] (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker#tensorflow_docker_requirements). Thanks!